# IF statement as Linear Constraint

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, constraints

I am  writing a linear program, but I am currently having troubles writing a certain constraint, which is basically an IF-statment. I will try to explain it as detailed as possible:

IF:
 $x_{it'}(t' + SRT(s)) >= t $, where $t' = 1, ..., t$

THEN:
$x_{it} = 0$.

Note that if the condition does not hold, $x_{it}$ does not necessarily has to be equal to 1.

Does anyone have any clue how to write this as a linear constraint?

Thank you very much.

Jeroen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i understood your constraint correctly, I would proceed as follows:

Introduce a new variable $\omega$, add a term in the objective function to minimize $\omega$, and use the following constraints

\begin{align}
x_{it} &\le \omega \quad \forall i\; \forall t\\
\omega &\ge 0 \\
\omega & \ge M \left(t-x_{it'}(t'+SRT(s))\right) \quad \forall i\; \forall t'=1,\cdots,t
\end{align}

($M$ is a large integer)

This way if $t\le x_{it'}(t'+SRT(s))$ for all $t'=1,\cdots,t$, then the right hand term in last constraint is negative, so the constraint becomes redundant with respect to $\omega\ge 0$. The objective function will minimize $\omega$ and set it to  $0$. So assuming $x_{it}\ge 0$, you will have $x_{it}\le \omega = 0$, i.e., $x_{it}=0$.

If $t> x_{it'}(t'+SRT(s))$ for at least one $t'=1,\cdots,t$, then the constraint $\omega\ge 0$ becomes redundant, and there is no reason for the solver to set $\omega$ and $x_{it}$ to $0$.